# Replace a Sachs Echo s with modern derailleur

Tags: derailleur-rear

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCMRf.jpg)looking for a replace of a Sachs Hurret Echo S   with a modern derailleur for use on a 14 28 free wheel.  Suggestions have been the Shimano Altus or Shimano Tourney neither actually work as lower cage hits the spokes when shifting to the large rear cog.

Bicycle is a Peugeot 80s racer 12 speed  -

Any suggestions for a basic replacement that works very welcome -

Thanks 
Stephen 
[image][image]

Comment: Have you straightened the bent derailer hanger?

Answer (score 2):

Freewheel 6 or 7 speed wheels typically have no clearance problems there. The issue is likely being caused by rear derailleur hanger misalignment and/or the low limit screw being adjusted too far out. There are many questions about both.

Update post-image: The derailleur hanger is bent. Put the shifter in high position and poke a 5mm 3-way wrench or  L-wrench into the pivot bolt of the new derailleur. Reef it around to make the plane of the pulley centerlines appear parallel with the plane of the cogs. Re-adjust the high limit if needed, double check it looks parallel, and you should be good. Eyeballing like this isn't great for latte speed generation bikes, but it's fine for 5 and 6 speed. If you want to baby the frame you could have it done with a proper tool, which I'd recommend in most other non-emergency cases.

Comment: thanks for the feedback: rear derailleur hanger misalignment and/or the low limit screw being adjusted too far out. Both have been checked and tested with two separate modern derailleurs -.  The modern derailleurs tested seem to too big; admittedly the  Shimano Tourney is long but the Altus also experiences the same issues - and is quite bulky.   Just for reference the Echo S was a modified Echo with the hanger angle adjusted to allow the 28 rear cog. - and clear the spokes - I'm sure there must be a smaller modern derailleur which can compare - ?

Comment: I think you should add some pictures. It's really unusual for spoke interference to even be possible on freewheel road bikes.

Comment: I concur - derailleur hanger bent is my guess, and the longer cage mechs show that worse because trigonometry.   Its not hitting spokes because of the new derailleur.

Comment: Another thought - I bet the old derailleur is bent back the other way, cancelling out a bend in the hanger.  A bike this old has had decades of usage on it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback: attaching a couple of pictures if I can find out how.   the derailleur hanger looks slightly out of straight compared to a Raleigh equivalent era.  However I don't believe this was an accident.  No broken paint etc. plus I know the history.  So seems factory set.  I don't wish to straighten unless its a last resort.  The rear forks are 123mm splay   The wheels are C700s (may have an impact on hub positioning ? as originals 27")

Comment: Looking at the picture, I count 5 cogs on that cassette. How does the bike have 12 speeds with 5 cogs? Your main problem is the bent hanger. It's pretty tweaked. You wont know if you need a new der until you correct that poor hanger. Then if it turns out that your der needs replaced, I would be looking for a 5 speed der, because your bike has either a 10 speed or 15 speed drive train.